# which one is Gabriel Fauré, Requiem, op. 48

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

There is a show, and it is written that they will perform

> Gabriel Fauré, Requiem, op. 48

I searched on Spotify so I found that Requiem for Faure has too many op (i don't know how to call them) and there is also something called (Pavane) as you see

[image]

I just need to know which "song" is the one they will perform in order to see if i like so i go and buy the ticket

sorry if i use a wrong vocabular in music, i am so bad :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fauré Requiem is made up of 8 separate sections, numbers 1-8 in your screenshot.

By itself, it wouldn't be long enough for a full concert, or a CD, so there will usually be some other shorter pieces as well. I guess the listing you're showing from Spotify is of a specific CD.  So, if you're checking the piece out, to see if you want to hear it live in a concert, you should listen to numbers 1-8.

Personally, I love the piece - I've heard it and sung in it several times, and I can't get tired of it.

Comment: Just for supplement: a *requiem* is the musical part of a specific *mass for the dead*, and just like in a normal mass, there are several occasions (marked points in liturgy) for music.

Comment: Good point @guidot -  I think Fauré's choice of movements for this requiem is said to be an individual choice, rather than standard for a requiem. But the piece was very personal to him, I believe connected with the death of his parents.